# Moving <div> from one <div> to another back and forth

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found lots of information on the web about how to remove, attach, prepend, etc.  Element from and to DIV.  Unfortunately I have a hard time making it work.

In my project, I will have to attach element to div and move them around on a grid (each grid cell being a div of it's own)  Bellow is a small script which mimics what I'm trying to do.

Here's the example (here's a link to JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mgR5b/25/):

HTML:

```
    <div id="LeftAndRightRow1" style="display:inline-block; height:100%;width:100%;border:1px solid black; background-color: red;">
       <div id="Left" style="display:inline-block; height:100%;width:45%; border:1px solid black; background-color: blue;">
        <button id="B1">B1</button>
        </div>
        <div id="Right" style="display:inline-block; height:100%;width:45%;border:1px solid black; background-color: pink;">
        <button id="B2">B2</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="LeftAndRightRow2" style="display:inline-block; height:100%;width:100%;border:1px solid black; background-color: red;">
        <div id="Left2" style="display:inline-block; height:100%;width:45%; border:1px solid black; background-color: yellow;">
            <button id="B3">B3</button>
        </div>
        <div id="Right2" style="display:inline-block; height:100%;width:45%;border:1px solid black; background-color: purple;">
            <button id="B4">B4</button>
        </div>
    </div>
   <br>
   <button id="SwapButton">Swap Button</button>
```

JQuery / JavaScript

Now, imagine I want to swap the container "Left" (I want to move the Div, not the button) to the second row (LeftAndRightRwo2).

I tried various things but not of them worked... My last attempt:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#SwapButton").click(function () {
        alert('trying to swap');
        $("#Left").remove();
        $("#LeftAndRightRow2").append($("#Left"));
    });
});
```

etc.

None of what I tried worked.

Can someone help understand how to move div from one place to another.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you remove an element, it is no longer on the DOM.  If you want to move a DOM element like that you need to store it in a variable.  Also you should use detach instead of remove as it is more efficient in this case.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#SwapButton").click(function () {
        var left = $('#Left');
        left.detach();
        $("#LeftAndRightRow2").append(left);
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah!  It worked... Great!  Thank you, thank you, thank you... and thank you again!  

I had tried detach() then append("#Left") but it did not work.  I don't think I was doing it right... You use var left = $('#Left'); then work with the variable.  That seems to work better.  when specifiying "#Left" directly as a parameter of append, the function did not see it as a element, but more like a string... Anyway thank you very much

Comment: Wow, I definitely didn't know `.detach()` existed. Thanks :D I learned something new today (+1).

Answer (score 1):

When you use `$("#Left").remove()` you are actually removing it from the DOM, so you can't recall it later with `$("#LeftAndRightRow2").append($("#Left"));`.

Try to save it, like this, in a variable:

**JS**

```
$("#SwapButton").click(function () {
    alert('trying to swap');
    var left = $("#Left");
    $(left).remove();
    $("#LeftAndRightRow2").append($(left));
});
```

Now the entire `div` moves from the right to the left.

**fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/mgR5b/26/

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is more of CSS and less in JS I have changed your mark up and CSS to get the result you are looking for

**Markup**

```
<div id="LeftAndRightRow1" class="rows">
    <div id="Left">
        <button id="B1">B1</button>
    </div>
    <div id="Right">
        <button id="B2">B2</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="LeftAndRightRow2"  class="rows">
    <div id="Left2">
        <button id="B3">B3</button>
    </div>
    <div id="Right2">
        <button id="B4">B4</button>
    </div>
</div>
<br style="clear:both;" />
<button id="SwapButton">Swap Button</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#SwapButton").click(function () {
        //alert('trying to swap');
       // $("#Left").remove();
        $("#LeftAndRightRow2").append($("#Left"));
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.rows{
display:block;
    clear:left;
}
.rows div{
float:left;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/habo/mgR5b/32/)